# how to access object inside a container

Tags: javascript, arrays, containers

I have a list of pictures that i want to add them to containers in order to selet them an add them to an animation fuction to optimize my code i made this array to add all of them once but the problem is how can i select object or container in this case ? i want to acces the container containing the image in order to apply a tween on it .

```
var containers = {};
var bitmaps = {};
var arrayOfThings = [
 { target: 'Ace', x: 90, y: 148, width: 276, height: 266},
 { target: 'K', x: 376, y: 148, width: 276, height: 266},
 { target: 'Q', x: 662, y: 148, width: 276, height: 266}
];  
arrayOfThings.forEach(function(thing) {
  var target = thing.target;
  var bm = bitmaps[target] = new createjs.Bitmap(loader.getResult(target));
  var container = containers[target] = new createjs.Container();
  container.addChild(bm);
  container.x = thing.x;
  container.y = thing.y;
  container.width = thing.width;
  container.height = thing.height;
  stage.addChild(container);
});
```

Comment: with "access the container" you mean a div, where the images should be applied to?

Comment: the pictures are stored on a html5 canvas but in my old code i did this :    Ace = new createjs.Bitmap(loader.getResult("Ace"));
 aceContainer = new createjs.Container();
 aceContainer.addChild(Ace);
 aceContainer.x = 90;
 aceContainer.y = 148;
 aceContainer.width = 276 ;
 aceContainer.height = 266;
 stage.addChild(aceContainer);
 
   so i would have an acces to the bitmape by calling the container aceContainer , in the new one how can i do the selection?

Comment: in other words in my old code to tween the bitmap i have only to call the container : tween (aceContainer) and the picture ace do the tween now in this new code how can i call in the tween function in order to animate the bitmape?